# How do I install a bitnami LAMP module by SSH command line?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, lamp, roundcube

This is a pretty straightforward question that I cannot seem to find an answer for. I already have a running Bitnami LAMP stack on an Amazon EC2 instance. Where do put the installer (bitnami-roundcube-1.0.1-0-module-linux-installer.run) and what commands do I need to do to run in?

I've tried:

`sudo ./bitnami-*`

And:

`sudo ./bitnami-* --mode text`

Both instances throw no errors but I also receive no messages nor a text mode installation process.

I also cannot find any files installed anywhere on the Ubuntu installation.

I downloaded this:
https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp/modules#roundcube

And I tried both 32-bit and 64-bit installers just in case I wasn't running 64-bit (which I'm pretty sure I am).